# How to paste what is on clipboard, sort and put it back to the clipboard

Tags: linux, clipboard

I would like to know if it's possible somehow to paste what it's in my clipboard into the terminal, sort it, and then put it back to my clipboard. I used to use the following command on OSX:

`pbpaste | sort | pbcopy`

Since I've changed to Linux I haven't managed to find a way to do the same thing.

Comment: Have to agree that this is off topic for Stack Overflow.  A valid question in and of itself however.  I would suggest that you try the Super User forum instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [xsel](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xsel) utility

```
xsel -o -b | sort | xsel -i -b
```

xsel allows you to manipulate input output including the clipboard. So you're reading the clipboard content and outputting to stdout with

```
xsel -b -o
```

Then passing that output to sort with the pipe, and then reading the stdout of sort into

```
xsel -b -i
```

Which takes the stdout of previous commands and sets it to your clipboard

EDIT : The -b flag specifies to use clipboard

Comment: Unfortunately the command prompts me the help message, so it seems not valid :(.

Comment: I made syntax mistake, will correct 1 second